# In the OG API, which hooks are available when a group admin adds or removes a user from a group?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

**Question:**

In the context of Organic Groups API, is there a hook that fires when an group administrator adds or removes a user from the group (or when a user self joins or self-removes their account)?

Ultimately, I was hoping for a hook that was fired around `og_group()` and `og_ungroup()` as that's how I best understand the API so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find all OG hooks [here](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!og!og.api.php/7).

You already mentioned two of them, but for the sake of a complete answer here are the hooks fired on membership add/edit/delete:

- [hook_og_membership_insert](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21og%21og.api.php/function/hook_og_membership_insert/7)
- [hook_og_membership_presave](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21og%21og.api.php/function/hook_og_membership_presave/7)
- [hook_og_membership_delete](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21og%21og.api.php/function/hook_og_membership_delete/7)

Also, as memberships actually are entities you can also use all hooks used for saving and deleting entities, like [hook_entity_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_update/7) and [hook_entity_delete](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_delete/7). You can find them in this [list](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/7).

Answer (score 0):

Well, this always seems to happen after offering a bounty. I stumbled upon these nifty hooks.

- [hook_og_membership_presave](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!og!og.api.php/function/hook_og_membership_presave/7)
- [hook_og_membership_delete](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!og!og.api.php/function/hook_og_membership_delete/7)

If anyone has a better idea, the bounty is still active..